# How to send mail from any mail id through java?

Tags: java, email

How to send mail from any mail id through java?
i meant how can we set from : address in mail any that we want.

Comment: this appears to be a programming question and will be migrated to Stack Overflow shortly.  i've associated your Stack Overflow and Super User accounts together and your Stack Overflow account should regain ownership after the migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard Java Mail API and just call [`setEnvelopeFrom()`](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPMessage.html#setEnvelopeFrom%28java.lang.String%29) on the message.

Comment: Why not use the `setFrom()` method?

Comment: MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);  
msg.setText(text);  
msg.setSubject(subject);  
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));  



it still shows the from as the authenticated user.  

ref:  
http://code.geekinterview.com/java/send-email-using-gmail-mail-server.html

Comment: @abc: So? You used setFrom() instead of setEnvelopeFrom(). What did you expect?

Comment: i expect from mail address can be any thing i want to set/.

Comment: Yes, it's just a string. That's why you can't trust "From" in an email and why it's so hard to fight spam.